# woocommerce if (is_product_category)

Tags: php, woocommerce

Need some help understanding why the code below isn't working. Copied from the woocommerce docs page https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/
and inserted into the theme (avada child theme) functions.php

I've modified the original code only in the category names - changing 'shirts' to 'merch' etc - to suit the categories descriptors I have used, and added the action and function lines.

```
    add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'print_below_desc');        
    function print_below_desc() 
    {
    if ( is_product_category() ) 
        {  
        if ( is_product_category( 'merch' ) ) 
        {
            echo 'Hi! Take a look at our sweet tshirts below.';
        }       
        elseif ( is_product_category( 'parts' ) ) 
        {
            echo 'Hi! Hungry for some gaming?';
        }       
        else 
        {
            echo 'Check out our products below.';
        }
    }
```

When used as shown above, I get no text added to the product, however if I remove the if statements and just echo a text string it shows up. i.e. this works:

```
    add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'print_below_desc');

    function print_below_desc() {
    echo 'Text string.';
    }
```

Given I have just copy/pasted the woo code, I'm not sure why it wont work for me. It's possible that there is something with avada that interferes, but I don't know what to look for.

Thanks

Comment: I would say that it is not seeing your categories, can you provide a link to your shop page?

Comment: **Advice:** `is_product_category()` is to be used on woocommerce category archive pages only. This conditional tag will return always `false` in all other pages (shop pages, product single pages, cart, checkout, my-account pages…)

Comment: Ok Thanx Loic.The site is on local machine only at this point not a live site.

Comment: What should be used on product single pages then?